# Query to build list of components from product list

Tags: google-sheets

I'm working in Google Sheets. I have a table of products to be assembled, and the number of each type of components makes them up. I'm looking to create a different sheet where I can choose the products and have it build a list of the components that are needed to build the list of products.

For example: A florist makes bouquets out of a couple different flowers. Each bouquet is entered into a table:

[image: Bouquet parameters]

I'm trying to set up a formula so when I build a list of all the bouquets being made that day, it will produce a list of all the flowers needed. Something that would look like this:

[image: Final Results]

Is there a way to have a query look for a certain value in a header and then pull all the values that correspond to values that are >0 in that column? Or a good work around?

Thanks alot,

Answer (score 0):

With for example, a matrix that shows what flowers (F) go into which bouquet (B):

[image: SO45445939 example]

and the day's (?) bouquet requirements in Row1, a simple [SUMPRODUCT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094294) formula (here in F3):

```
=sumproduct(B$1:E$1,B3:E3)
```

and copied down to suit should suffice.